# Show the images from the shared drive with C# MVC

Tags: development, jquery, asp.net, html, mvc

I want to show the images from the shared drive, I have published the solution and hosted in the IIS and created one directory named as "Images" which directs to the another server's shared folder having images.
So I have to show those images in the web browser with C# MVC.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this blog,

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/working-with-images-in-Asp-Net-mvc-framework/

Please let me know if you have any doubts. And mark as answer if this one helped.

Comment: Hello Gowtham,
Thanks for your feedback,
I have to do this without image class, I'm passing the only image name with model to the JsonResult and after that I am binding the html within the jquery success function.
So over-here I am passing the physical folder name. Instead of this physical path I have to change this to the network path, 
Can you have any idea to do the same?